# How do you attach audio to a prompt?

Tags: javascript, audio, prompt

I having difficulties trying to attach audio to the prompt, "What is your name", with the audio "images/whatisyourname.wav".I have no idea how to attach these two different elements together.

I've been working on this for hours now, and way to frustrated to think properly. I do not know javascript at all, so please, any suggests will be beyond my knowledge in this language.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>eve_</title>
<link rel="icon" rel="preload" href="images/evecircle.png" />

<style>
#video {
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}

</style>

 <script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

</style>

<body onload="delayedAlert();">

<script>

var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 3000);
}

function slowAlert() {
 var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
 const audio2 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];


audio.play(); 
var myvar1;alert('...Hello?')

audio2.play();
var myvar2;alert('Hello?');

const name = prompt('What is your name?')
const sentence = 'Hello' + name +',I am Eve. What does a' +name +'look like?';
responsiveVoice.speak(sentence, "US English Female", {rate: 0.7});

}


</script>

 <audio>
  <source src="images/hellllloooo.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

 <audio>
  <source src="images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

 <audio>
 <source src="images/whatisyourname.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>



        <video autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" id="video" src="images/secondnew.mp4" width="1300px" height="auto" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1;" >
        Video not supported.
         </video>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "attach audio to a prompt"? What are you trying to accomplish? They're pretty separate things

Comment: This all is for an art based assignment. My installation, or this code rather, is attempting to fool viewers into believing this being is actually possessing an intellect when in actuality, it is a series of code allowing this conversation to be somewhat believable.

Comment: OK then, in Javascript terms, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: by having both the prompt and the verbal audio file, that is repeating the initial text, instructs this to be a greater being. Communicating with the user in multiple forms, audibly and visually.

Comment: When the prompt appears, an audio file with play at the same time as the prompt's apperance

Comment: Similar to the alerts, how they have audio when they appear, im trying to do the exact same but with a prompt, where you enter in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will help you. I think you just call stop method.

```
function slowAlert() {
    var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    var audio2 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];
    var audio3 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2];


    audio.play(); 
    var myvar1;alert('...Hello?')
    audio.stop();

    audio2.play();
    var myvar2;alert('Hello?');
    audio2.stop();

    audio3.play();
    const name = prompt('What is your name?')
    audio3.stop();
    const sentence = 'Hello' + name +',I am Eve. What does a' +name +'look like?';
    responsiveVoice.speak(sentence, "US English Female", {rate: 0.7});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to embed the audio file in the DOM. Something like this should work. You'll need to refactor:

```
var promptAudio = new Audio('promp-sound.mp3');
promptAudio.volume = 1;

function promptSound() {
    promptAudio.currentTime = 0;
    promptAudio.play();

    // call your alert
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble getting responsiveVoice to play at the exact same time you alert/prompt something, you have to use a callback, like this:

```js
const name = prompt('What is your name?')
alertAndSpeak('Hello' + name +', I am Eve. What does a ' + name + ' look like?');

function alertAndSpeak(text) {
  responsiveVoice.speak(text, "US English Female", {
    rate: 0.7,
    onstart: () => alert(text),
    onend: null
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
```